# Can't show origin at (1,1) : R base graphics

Tags: r, plot

I want to show the origin of the plot at (1,1) but can't do it with the following R code. I would add some line segments later to the plot.

```
xMax <- 600
yMax <- 150
plot(0, type = "n", 
    xlab = "XVal",
    ylab = "YVal",
    xlim = c(1, xMax), 
    ylim = c(1, yMax),
    xaxs="i", 
    yaxs="i"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add it using `axis`:

```
xMax <- 600
yMax <- 150
plot(0, type = "n", 
    xlab = "XVal",
    ylab = "YVal",
    xlim = c(1, xMax), 
    ylim = c(1, yMax),
    xaxs="i", 
    yaxs="i"
)
axis(1, at = 1)  ## add this
axis(2, at = 1)  ## add this
```

[image: plot with origin at (1, 1)]